# Can anybody suggest me references for functional analysis? My main concern is to do examples as much as i can.

Tags: reference-request

Can anybody suggest me references for functional analysis? My main concern is to workout examples as much as i can do. Also if there is any web resources to help mein this regard ?

Thanks for giving me time.

Comment: kreyzig is a good introductory text.

Comment: Brezis's "Functional Analysis" has finally been translated into English

Comment: Terrence Tao has a blog with a nice set of notes. Here's [a sample](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/245b-notes-11-the-strong-and-weak-topologies/).

Comment: @DavidMitra That is really helpful thank you.

Comment: Kreyzig is better for an introductory text while Brezis's a more advanced one.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Course-Functional-Analysis-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/1441930922/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1337127677&sr=8-1

Comment: Thanks to all of you for giving me suggessions. I will search in my library first.